# How to create a new folder in amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, filesystems, aem

I am using AEM with Amazon S3. AEM provides connector for S3 but normally S3 store everything in flat structure, my requirement is to create a new folder in my S3 bucket after the folder reach a particular storing limit. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm interested in the use case, i.e. what will it achieve? We can probably come up with another solution...

Comment: We just have a limitation to store the fixed number of objects per folder.

Comment: Don't think that's a S3 limitation but in such a case S3 may not be the best option for your setup. Rewriting is very difficult and will have cascading impacts on operations and support (from Adobe) as you will rewrite core connector. AEM blobs are identified by a guid kind of structured name. In a FIleDataStore the first six characters form folder structure. In S3 they form namespace. Using new folders will be complex especiall for all scenarios. Is EBS mount an option?

Comment: so is there any way to extend the connector and write our own functions for creating new folder?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not extensible and does not provide a pluggable service registry interface to change the way folders are managed.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is No.

AEM follows it's own structure and it is not customisable i.e. you cannot override the folder creation logic. This is tightly integrated into the NodeStore way's of referencing the S3 objects via referencing so changing it will be a huge task. It's not impossible to achieve (by rewriting the connector) but it cannot be done by a configuration in AEM 6.0-6.2 yet.

Comment: Thanks you, well i am new with AEM so is there any way to rewrite connector.